# Getting Error Cannot find any .csproj or .fsproj file for your project! Please fix this error and try again while trying to install Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, nuget-package, csproj, fsproj

I have just installed nuget package manager and using nugent package manager I am trying to install Selenium Web Driver for the first time, but i am getting the error "Cannot find any .csproj or .fsproj file for your project! Please fix this error and try again". I don't understand what this error means and why its asking for those file extensions, I have a blank folder there are no files in the project.

Anybody know what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to open C# / .NET project in your vscode first. This problem occurs when you try to install a nuget package into a non C# / .NET project or inside an empty workspace.

**To initialize a C# project :**

- Open a terminal/command prompt and navigate to the folder in which you'd like to create the app.
- Enter the following command in the command shell :
  `dotnet new console`
- You will have a notification at the bottom right saying : "Required assets to build and debug are missing. Add them?" select "Yes".

Now you should be able to install your nuget package by using the nuget package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was a file placement I have anaconda and vscode and the green "vscode insider" I did a pip install on my computer command prompt because I couldn't use it on the anaconda or vscode then I had to move the file to the vscode and it took care of the issue